# How to extract text out of QuarkXPress file in linux?

Tags: text, file-format

Is there a way to extract the text from [QuarkXPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuarkXPress)?

(Preferably, I would not want to use QuarkXPress itself, but free software compatible with it.)

Comment: What format does it produce?

Comment: @terdon I believe the format is also called QuarkXPress

Comment: Proprietary formats are always somewhat problematic but let's say out of curiosity we want to try and see if there is anything in the available Linux tool set that could help, is there some way a sample *.qxd or whatever file format it is, could be posted somewhere we can download and try experimenting on the sample? Keep in mind that Quark documents apparently have different formats depending on Quark versions, so the sample should reflect the same version as the actual documents you are trying to extract text from.

Comment: @user454038 I don't have them on hand. I'll try and get one when I have access again.

Comment: @PyRulez yes, please do so, we can't really help without it.

Comment: `file` and `strings` are a good start.

Comment: @terdon I wasn't sure if people were familiar with it already. It will probably take a week before I can get it. (Sorry.)

Comment: @waltinator See my [follow up question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251498/tips-for-parsing-proprietary-file-formats).

Comment: @user454038 I can't share a file, so [I asked this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251498/tips-for-parsing-proprietary-file-formats).

Comment: Would love to see this, but as far as I can tell QuarkXpress files are no longer in a human-readable format by default. I'm not sure what it would take to decode them.